# VBA Outook 2010 - Coding the ItemAdd Event

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I've seen a number of posts on various sites addressing this question, but have yet to get it to work. Maybe I'm dense, dunno, but here goes:
Event doesn't seem to want to fire.
Code within the `ThisOutlookSession` 
At the top prior to subs/functions:

```
'Declare event handler
Public WithEvents myOutlookItems As Outlook.Items 
Private Sub Application_Startup() 
    Set myOutlookItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items 
End Sub 
Public Sub myOutlookItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object) 
    If TypeName(Item) = MailItem Then 
        MsgBox ("Got a message") 
    End If 
End Sub'
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have a look at macro security. By default, unsigned macro's are disabled

Comment: Thanks but that is pretty much open and I have other macros which are firing (i. e. application_itemsend )

Comment: like @DmitryStreblechenko said  Use `olMail` or `"MailItem"` it should work.

Answer (score 1):

TypeName returns a string, so your code should be

```
If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
```

Or you can check the value of the Class property (all OOM objects expose it):

```
If Item.Class = olMail Then ' olMail== 43
```

Comment: Thanks @DmitryStreblechenko ! I had already altered it to: "If TypeName(Item) = MailItem Then"  But I like your approach better so will change it to      "If Item.Class = olMail"